# Correct syntax for replacing multiple occurrences with PHP's preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've gone over other questions from stack overflow with similar ideas but none seem to resemble closely enough what I'm trying to do.

Seems simple, but I'm in a pickle.
I'm trying to replace multiple occurrences of a line break (`\n`) with only one line break, so people won't be able to submit more than one line break at a time.
Here's what I've tried.

```
$text = "Foo\n\n\nbar!\n\nfoobar!";
$text = preg_replace("#\n+#", "\n", $text);
echo $text;
```

The expected returned statement would be:

```
Foo\nbar!\nfoobar!
```

But no cigar!
I tried several but none seemed to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What does get printed then? `preg_replace("#\n+#", "\n", $text)` really *does* produce `Foo\nbar!\nfoobar!` (where the line breaks are printed of course, not the literals `\` and `n`).

Comment: Okay, so you've told. But again: **what does get printed then?**

Comment: have you tried echoing it within <pre> tags, just to make sure of what gets really printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in the solution, skip to the last line.

Here's what ended up happening. I had a `div` tag in html that contained certain information.
When a user hits a button, a JS code runs that converts that `div` to an `input` textbox, and sets the value of that textbox as the html of the original div - while replacing all occurrences of `<br>` with `\n` to create real line breaks.
The form then got submitted via ajax to the server.

When I tried to replace the line breaks in PHP, none of the above suggestions helped, for the simple reason that it wasn't (curiously enough) a "real" linebreak character. What got submitted to the server was the literal `\n`.
You'd think escaping the backslash in `\n`, as suggested by ghostdog74 would solve the problem but it did not. I tried escaping it several different ways but nothing seemed to help.

I ended up referencing some old regex material and found that:

> Many flavors also support the \Q...\E escape sequence. All the characters between the \Q and the \E are interpreted as literal characters. E.g. \Q*\d+*\E matches the literal text *\d+*. The \E may be omitted at the end of the regex... This syntax is supported by the JGsoft engine, Perl, PCRE... [[source]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Following that, here's the piece of code that solved my problem:

```
$text = preg_replace('#[\Q\n\E]+#', "\n", $text);
```

Thank you everybody for all your help! +1 for all :)

Comment: That will replace any backslashes and "n" letters in the input since everything is inside a character class - those should be normal rather than square brackets. Also, using single quotes and triple-escapes (`pattern = '#(\\\n)+#';`) would work correctly in this case too, but it is admittedly ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to check for all three varieties of line breaks:

```
$text = "Foo\n\r\n\n\rbar!\n\nfoobar!";
$text = preg_replace('#(\r\n|\r|\n)+#m', "\n", $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: still no cigar... I paid close attention to the the single quotes you used and the 'm' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Bart: yes, and neither are the single quotes, though neither matter. The point of my post was the support of Windows/UNIX/Mac line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Foo\n\n\nbar!\n\nfoobar!";
$s = split("\n+",$text);
print_r( implode("\n",$s)); #this will join the string with newline
print_r( implode("\\n",$s)); # this will have literal \n in your string
```

Comment: tried this out as well, does not seem to work. I should mention I'm getting my data from a textarea. It's possible my input doesn't contain \n but a different char, I suppose, but I tried echoing it out and it certainly does not look that way